# android background task if my application is killed

Tags: android, background, android-alarms, worker, android-jobscheduler

My task is that, send notification before/after an event in Android device. I tried AlarmManager, Worker, JobScheduler, but when the user killed my application, none of these background tasks can work. Is there a method to do this simple task in Android?

thx
Zamek

Answer (score 0):

You should use `WorkManager` to guarantee execution even if the app exits.

[Introduction to work manager](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-workmanager-2083bcfc4712)

[Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

[Useful Codelab to grasp the concept](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#0)

Comment: Sorry I tried WorkManager, but it is not worked me. The restriction is that must send a notification at exact  time, even if the application swiped out. Is there a trick for this what I don't know? When I run application it always send a message well, but when the user swiped out this application notification is not coming. And then when the user restart app. after the expected time, notification is coming, but is too late. I want to send a notification about "do this now", and after "did you do it?"

Answer (score 0):

i am a bit late... sorry
but **workManager** should work because by docs, work can be of 2 types (might be more),

1. [periodic work request](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest)
2. [oneTimeWorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/OneTimeWorkRequest)

periodic work request should be set to minimum interval of 900,000 milliseconds which is 15 minutes,and it is guaranteed to work at anytime but in within interval .

if you want your task (notification) must trigger whenever you want try using **[Broadcast Receiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver)**

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't works well, because every vendor handling this policy by own method. For example xiaomi is differs to pure android, it needs to set permissions by user only, and I don't have idea, how can I trigger it programatically. The best method for me is firebase push message

Comment: @zamekz okay i know what are you talking about and i am still newbie i would like if you check this [app](https://github.com/utsav-devadiga/DailyPill) out idk much but it works with alarm manager with broadcast but the topic was about background task so for example lets say uploading pic to server this can be done with help of work manager